# If I am given $\gcd (a, b), \ \gcd (b, c), \ \gcd (a, c)$ and $abc$, how to find $\operatorname{lcm} (a, b, c)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If I am given $\gcd (a, b), \ \gcd (b, c), \ \gcd (a, c)$ and $abc$, how to find $\operatorname{lcm} (a, b, c)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let p be a prime factor of abc.  Let m be the highest factor of p that divides abc.  Let j,j, and l be the highest factors of p that divide the gcds.  Sort these powers from least to highest.  Wolog j =j <= l. [Note: the lower two powers will always be equal.  I'll explain why below.]

Let k = m - l - j.  Then k is the highest power of p that divides lcm (a,b,c).  Do this for each of the prime factors of abc.  The result will give you the prime factorization of lcm (a,b,c).

Why.  Well suppose $p^j|a $ and $p^{l \ge j}|b $ and $p^{k \ge j}|c$.  Then $p^j|\gcd (a,b) $ $p^j|\gcd (a,c) $, $p^l|\gcd (b,c)$, $p^k|\text {lcm} (a,b,c) $ and $p^{m = j + k +l} $.  We need to find k given m,j, and l. Well, k = m - j -l.

Comment: thank yousir but you have explained in a very high manner... i am not able to understand some notations. it would be a favour if you explain it to me simply..

Comment: Example:[a = 12; b = 450; c=280] gcd(a,b)=6=2\*3, gcd(a,c) = 4=$2^2$, gcd(b,c) = 30=2\*3\*5.  abc =1512000 =$ 2^6*3^3*5^3*7$.  2|6, 2|30, 4|4 and 64|abc.  =>2|b, 4|a or c and 8|c or a => 8|lcm(a,b,c). 3|6, 3$\not \mid$4, 3|30, 27|abc => 3|a or c and   9|c or a => 9|lcm(a,b,c). 5$\not \mid$6, 5$\not \mid$4, 5|30 => 5$\not \mid$a, 5|b or c, 25|c or b => 25|lcm(a,b,c). 7$\not \mid$6,4, or 30 but 7|abc.  So 7 divides one and only one of a,b, or c.  7|lcm(a,b,c) so lcm(a,b,c) = 8*9*25*7 = 12600.

Answer (score 7):

Hint:

If $d_1=\gcd(a,b)$, $d_2=\gcd(b,c)$, $d_3=\gcd(c,a)$ then
$$\text{lcm}(a,b,c)= \frac{abc \gcd(a,b,c)}{d_1 d_2 d_3}$$